# What's the best way to filter an array to create another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I would like to filter the items from an array based on a string and save them to a new array to then perform some other functions on that second array. How would I best achieve this?

Here is what I have so far.

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var num = i;
    var item = array.entries[i];
    var str = item.content;    
    var newArray = new Array();

    if (str.indexOf("filter") !== -1) {
                // If the content of the item contains a given string then ad it to the array.
                newArray.push(item);

        if (num === array.length) {
            // When we reach the end of the first array, perform something on the new array.
            doSomeFunction();
        }
    }

    function doSomeFunction() {
        // Now do something with the new array
        for (var j = 0; j < newArray.length; j++) {
            // Blah, blah, blah...
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: num will never reach array.length, so it's not a good way to check if you're at the end of the array - also, don't declare a function in your loop

Answer (score 2):

ECMAScript 5 supports the `filter` method on arrays.

for example:

```
> [1,2,3,4].filter(function(v) { return v % 2 == 0})
[ 2, 4 ]
```

you may refer to [MDN's document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to see the usage.

But note that this is not supported in some browsers, for compatibility issue, you may consider using [es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) or [underscore](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore).

in your case for doing the work on string arrays. you can use `filter` together with `map`

for example, to filter all strings starting with 'index', then take the trailing number from them.

```
var ss = [
  "index1",
  "index2",
  "index3",
  "foo4",
  "bar5",
  "index6"
];

var nums = ss.filter(function(s) {
  return /^index/.test(s);
}).map(function(s) {
  return parseInt(s.match(/(\d+)$/)[1], 10);
});

console.log(nums);
```

the above script gives you `[1,2,3,6]`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
function arrayFromArray(a,f){
  var b=[];
  for (var x=0;x<a.length;x++) {
    if (f(a[x])) {
      b.push(a[x]);
    }
  }
  return b;
}


function predicateIsEven(i){
  return i%2==0;
}


var arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6];

var evens=arrayFromArray(arr,predicateIsEven);
```